# Find elements in one vector and replace by the equivalents in another vector in R

Tags: r, replace

I have 3 columns of names (corresponding to different diatom species). The first column is the current name of my species, the second column is the "old" (i.e. not used any more) name of the species and the third one is the "new" (i.e. after taxonomic update) name of the species.

For each value in the first column I need to find it in the second column and, if found, I need to replace it by the updated name (stored in the third column). So for example, given this matrix:

```
Column 1                    Column 2                Column 3
Achnanthes.atomus           Amphora.coffeaeformis   Halamphora.coffeaeformis
Achnanthes.biasolettiana    Achnanthes.atomus       Achnanthidium.atomus
```

Achnanthes.atomus found in column 1 (first row), should be identified in column 2 (second row) and replaced by its "new name" Achnanthidium.atomus (column 2, second row).

My matrix is called Diatosdef. If I do this, it works:

```
colnames(Diatosdef) <- gsub("Achnanthes.atomus","Achnanthidium.atomus",colnames(Diatosdef))
```

But I need to do it species by species, and I have almost 100 species

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks!

P.S: I found that I can do it in Excel with the vlookup function, but I am still looking for a way of doing it in R

Comment: Hi! My matrix is named "Diatosdef". So if I do this, it works:   colnames(Diatosdef) <- gsub("Achnanthes.atomus","Achnanthidium.atomus",colnames(Diatosdef))  But I need to do it species by species, and I have almost 100 species...

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- function(x, mat){
    if(x %in% mat[,2]) mat[which(mat[,2]==x), 3]
    else x
}

Diatosdef[,1] <- sapply(Diatosdef[,1], fun, mat = Diatosdef)
```

Comment: Thanks Jim! This looks promising! The problem is that the columns have different number of observations (column 1 = factor w/ 948 levels; column 2 = factor w/ 89 levels; column 3 = factor w/ 89 levels), because not all the species names in column 1 need to be replaced. Thus, when applying your function I get:  Error in Ops.factor(Diatomcodes[, 2], x) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
for(i in matrix[:1]){
  if(matrix[i:1] == matrix[i:2])
    matrix[i:1] = matrix[i:3]
}
```

maybe the syntax isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks Daniele. Unfortunately when I do it I get this error: for(i in Diatosdef[:1]){
Error: inesperado ':' in "for(i in Diatosdef[:"  When trying to change the syntax U get this:  for(i in Diatosdef[1]){
+ if(Diatosdef[i:1] == Diatosdef[i:2])
+ Diatosdef[i:1] = Diatosdef[i:3]
+ }
Error in Ops.data.frame(Diatosdef[i:1], Diatosdef[i:2]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
Además: Warning messages:
1: In i:1 : numerical expression has 948 elements: only the first used
2: In i:2 : numerical expression has 948 elements: only the first used

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace ':' with ',' . Sorry but now I haven't Rstudio so I can't try this :(

Comment: Thanks Daniele, but I still get an error: Error in i:1 : Argumento NA/NaN
Además: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(Diatomcodes, i:1) : NAs introducidos por coerción